# Laravel schedule list shows different schedule and just one runs

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I've created three schedulers and I'm facing two issues:

1. The `schedule:list` "Interval" value is not aligned with the real schedule
2. Just one schedule is really running (the first one)

The schedule list shows the wrong interval (different from the schedule) for the last two.

```
php artisan  schedule:list
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------+
| Command                                                         | Interval  | Description | Next Due                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------+
| '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' socialReviews:refreshGoogleToken | * * * * * |             | 2023-09-15 10:09:00 +00:00 |
| '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' socialReviews:retrieveGoogle     | 0 * * * * |             | 2023-09-15 11:00:00 +00:00 |
| '/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' socialReviews:retrieveFacebook   | 0 * * * * |             | 2023-09-15 11:00:00 +00:00 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

The Kernel class definition:

```
/**
 * Class Kernel.
 */
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\RefreshGoogleToken',
        'App\Console\Commands\RetrieveGoogleSocialReviews',
        'App\Console\Commands\RetrieveFacebookSocialReviews'
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('socialReviews:refreshGoogleToken')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('socialReviews:retrieveGoogle')->everyTenMinutes();
        $schedule->command('socialReviews:retrieveFacebook')->everyTenMinutes();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

I'm using ofelia scheduler, to run every five minutes with the command:

```
php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Laravel version: `"laravel/framework": "^8.40"`

I already investigated, debugged and tried many changes, but it still like this.

Comment: So you want to run the last 2 commands every 10 minutes, right?

Comment: have you tried ``->cron('*/10 * * * *')`` instead of ``->everyTenMinutes``??

Comment: I want to run the last 2 commands every 10 minutes. Right. @MitKathrotia
I tried the cron now and it worked. So, it's a bug with the textual scheduler. Right?

Comment: Yes, maybe there is something wrong with that particular function.

Comment: I've tried it and i get `*/10 * * * *` when using `everyTenMinutes(`) on laravel 10

Comment: Yeah, for the 8.4 version.. thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug for `Laravel 8.4` version. Changing from

```
    $schedule->command('socialReviews:retrieveGoogle')->everyTenMinutes();
    $schedule->command('socialReviews:retrieveFacebook')->everyTenMinutes();
```

to

```
    $schedule->command('socialReviews:retrieveGoogle')->cron('*/10 * * * *');
    $schedule->command('socialReviews:retrieveFacebook')->cron('*/10 * * * *');
```

Solved both issues, and all commands are running now like expected.